# column not created in sqlite database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
public static final String Database_Name="content.db";
public static final int Database_Version=1;
public static final String Table_Name="images";
public static final String Column1="contentid";
public static final String Column2="content_type";
public static final String Column3="content";
public static final String Column4="has_update";
public static final String Column5="server";
public static final String Column6="_id";
public static final String Create_Database="CREATE TABLE" + Table_Name +
        "(" + Column6 + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ Column1 + "LONG," + Column2 + "TEXT," 
+ Column3 + "TEXT," + Column4 + "INTEGER," + Column5 + "INTEGER" + ");";
```

i am creating an sqlite table in android using above declaration and exection the code executes successfully but in logcat gives an exception saying column content has not been created ,what can cause that problem i am unable to understand.please help.............

this is the logcat statement

```
02-17 19:36:15.658: E/SQLiteLog(31602): (1) table images has no column named content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you copy/paste the error message?

I think one problem in your create query is that you're not going to have space between the columns names and types. Don't know if that's the actual problem, but sounds problematic enough to me.

EDIT:
I mean you're create query should look like

```
public static final String Create_Database = 
"CREATE TABLE " + Table_Name +
        " (" + Column6 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        Column1 + " LONG, " + 
        Column2 + " TEXT, " + 
        Column3 + " TEXT, " + 
        Column4 + " INTEGER, " + 
        Column5 + " INTEGER);";
```

Comment: i don't know what i did but i think i have solved this problem but now in another table i am having the same error a column is not created in the table can someone explain me the cause of the problem what am i doing wrong here???

Comment: Chances are, the other CREATE TABLE DDL is just as broken as the one you gave an example of. Inspect the query string before you execute it. You're missing spaces between keywords and column/table names.